# How do I pass arguments to Thin in Rails 3.1+ to configure SSL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, thin

I'm working on enabling SSL on a Rails app in a staging environment that uses the Thin gem. It seems like I'm only a few steps away. I've set `config.force_ssl = true` in `config/environments/staging.rb`.

Since I haven't told Thin where the SSL certificate and key are, rails puts `!! Invalid request`. At least I think that's why it's doing that.

I found that Thin can accept arguments to determine the location of the SSL certificate and key files, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7862689/783601). However, I can't figure out where to tell Rails to start Thin with these arguments. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you're starting from the command line, you can run `thin start --ssl` instead of `rails server` (plus any other options listed in [How can I pass SSL options into "rails server" in Rails 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604303/how-can-i-pass-ssl-options-into-rails-server-in-rails-3-0/7862689#7862689))

Comment: Thanks, but I've already successfully gotten SSL working with Unicorn and Nginx.