# How to include SSL Certificate in Rails 3 project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, thin

I have developed a Rails 3 project which uses `thin` as server, along with Devise and Doorkeeper for Authentication

I would like to add SSL Certificate in my project. I have seen some posts which describes how to use SSL Certificate in Rails 3 Project,but none of then showing how to add certificate in Rails 3 project.

I have enabled `config.force_ssl = true` in my `applicationcontroller.rb`, and I tried starting thin server like:

```
thin start --ssl
```

It works without adding certificate and I can now access my website with `https://` (Getting Certificate not verified Warning from Browser. I hope this is because my certificate is not verified by CA).

Recently I have seen a post showing how to add SSL Certificate in Rails 3 project; 
[How can I pass SSL options into "rails server" in Rails 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604303/how-can-i-pass-ssl-options-into-rails-server-in-rails-3-0/7862689#7862689)

```
:SSLEnable        => true,
:SSLVerifyClient    => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE,
:SSLPrivateKey        => OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.open(current_dir + "/config/certs/server.key").read),
:SSLCertificate         => OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.open(current_dir + "/config/certs/server.crt").read),
:SSLCertName    => [ [ "CN", WEBrick::Utils::getservername ] ]
```

Is this the right way of adding the certificate? Each time when I try to start the server I need to specify these options.

Is there any other method to include certificate path in my project config (or include certificate in my project) so that there is no need for specifying certificate path each and every time I start my server?

Any help is appreciated....

Comment: You will use thin in production?

Comment: yes i am planning to use thin server in production....

Comment: Hm, may be it will be better to use nginx + unicorn?(or passenger)

Comment: i am using windows machine,i thaught of using passenger initially but i heard it only works on unix machine.....

Comment: adding ssl certificate is common to all server....right?

Answer (score 4):

Here I found answer about adding ssl to thin:

[Thin with SSL support and ruby-debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8753566/thin-with-ssl-support-and-ruby-debug)

If you want to add ssl to nginx (I advice to use nginx in production) here is described how to add certificate to nginx

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpSslModule

```
server {
  listen               443;
  ssl                  on;
  ssl_certificate      /path_to_certificate/cert.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key  /path_to_certificate/cert.key;
  keepalive_timeout    70;
}
```