# Create ssl certificate for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate

I am using ruby 2.0.0, rails 3.2.6 and running my project in EC2 server.

Now I want to generate ssl certificate to my project.

Where  I can find the certificate and how should I include into my project.Can anyone guide me?

Answer (score 1):

> Now I want to generate ssl certificate to my project.

I am presuming that you are talking about creating self-signed certificate. Follow these steps to generate a self -signed certificate:

Generate a Private key and CSR: `openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout key.pem -out req.pem`

Above command will create your private key `key.pem` and a CSR `req.pem`

Generate a self-signed Cert: `openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in req.pem -signkey key.pem -out cert.pem`

Above command will use `key.pem` and `req.pem` and will create certificate `cert.pem`.

You have to follow the prompts given by above commands and provide answers accordingly.

If you do not want a self-signed certificate, then you need to buy SSL certificate from a vendor. There are numerous companies which provide SSL certificate. You need to create a private key and a CSR (certificate signing request). you can follow 1st command above to achieve this. Once done, then you have to provide the CSR to the SSL vendor who will get you the certificate.

There are a lot of details around this process. Please check http://www.sslshopper.com/ for more information around SSL.

> how should I include into my project

please check below links:

http://www.buildingwebapps.com/articles/79189-using-ssl-in-rails-applications

[How to include SSL Certificate in Rails 3 project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14681797/how-to-include-ssl-certificate-in-rails-3-project)