# No data received when running "thin start"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, thin

I am using ruby 1.9.3 and rvm. I would like to run a thin server with --ssl option. I read in some answers that running "thin start --ssl" should do the trick.
But in my development environment when I run thin start --ssl the terminal runs:

```
Using rack adapter
Thin web server (v1.5.1 codename Straight Razor)
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop
And in my web-browser in localhost:3000:

No data received
Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data.
Here are some suggestions:
Reload this webpage later.
Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data.
```

When I run the same command with "rails s thin" it work though, with a different message:

```
Booting Thin
Rails 3.2.11 application starting in development on http:// 0. 0. 0 .0 :3000
Call with -d to detach
Ctrl-C to shutdown server
```

I don't know why this happens (maybe because of rvm) but thin is working propely. I wanted to run the first vertion "thin start --ssl" because I couldn't set this ssl option in the "rails s" command.

Comment: What status code does your browser return? I wonder whether it's because you don't have the SSL certificates setup for Thin? Did you setup anything like that?

Comment: Well, I tried to run a rails server with thin and pass on SSL certificates as suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604303/how-can-i-pass-ssl-options-into-rails-server-in-rails-3-0/7862689#7862689. However, I receive status code "Error 107 (net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR): SSL protocol error."

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason why I had "No data received". If anyone has the same error:

I ran "thin start --ssl" so my server would only respond to https requets. All the http requests were not answered, so that's why there was no data (stupid). By default http requests goes to port 80 while https requests goes to port 443.

"thin start --ssl" works fine for debugging ssl locally and you can test your whole application by forcing ssl in the application controller (so you don't find yourself in the same situation, with no data received).

Answer (score 0):

A much easier (and more real world) solution is to run a web server (like nginx) in front of your rails app.  This web server would listen for both http and https traffic, and then just pass everything over to port 3000 to the Rails (thin) server.

Comment: I wanted to setup SSL locally thinking it would be easier than to configure my production server with nginx and passenger installed at first. I don't know if the problem I am having in my application is due to the SSL configuration in the server or some other ssl_requirement file in the application.

Comment: How do I set up this server? I have installed passenger and nginx to my ubuntu but I still don't know how to configure them to work locally.

Comment: Here is a link to a sample config.  All you really are doing is having nginx listen on 80/433 and then pointing both listeners to the same Rails app: http://candidcode.com/2009/09/12/sample-nginx-with-phusion-passenger-configuration-file-to-enable-ssl/